# Visual Studio 2012 - Only Showing Publish to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I am having a issue when trying to publish a web project in visual studio. normally I just publish to a folder on my computer but now when I go to do that I only have options for azure.

does anyone know whats going wrong or how to fix this??
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select `New...` from the `Select or Import a publish profile` dropdown:

[image: Select New...]

After that you will be prompted to enter a name for the profile.  Put in a name such as "local".

Then for that profile you can select to publish to the filesystem:

[image: Publish to FS]

The next time you publish, you can just choose the same profile.